# get container parameter in my custom classes Symfony2

Tags: symfony, service, configuration, containers

I have the class, it declare as service. When I `get()` my service I run some method and this method require two params what I want to let user configure in `config.yml`. How I can get these parameters in this class? Maybe exist some way to do this in my service definition? Or I need extend my class from ContainerAware (if I am right its bad practice)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject parameters into your service using `%param_name%` syntax

**services.yml**

```
services:
    your_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\YourClass
        arguments: [@some.other.service, %my_parameter%]
```

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    my_parameter: my_value
```

Comment: this works, thanks, but what if I want to get the configuration parameters of some bundle?

Comment: you can use any parameter defined as a ``parameter`` in whole application, it might be also a parameter added by bundle

Comment: Hi! In my case, I want to inject @service_container to custom class, but this class must extend from Controller, otherwise, the container is null, it's correct or something is wrong? Tanks in advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use call them using the constructor

```
acme.your_service:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\YourService
    arguments: [%param1%]
```

in the class

```
class YourService {
   protected $param1;

   public function __construct($param1) {
      $this->param1 = $param1;
   }
}
```